# What can be concluded about $f\ $?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, contraction-operator

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. Assume that $Y$ is a discrete metric space and that $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a contraction. What can be concluded about $f\ $?

What I observe is that if there exist $x, y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$ then we have $$1 = d(f(x),f(y)) \leq c\ d (x,y)$$ for some $0 \lt c \lt 1.$

Now let $x_0 \in X.$ Let there exist an $y \in X$ such that $f(y) \neq f(x_0).$ Then since $Y$ is discrete it follows that $d(f(x_0),f(y)) = 1.$ Let us choose $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt 1.$ Then by continuity of $f$  (any contraction map is Lipschitz and hence uniformly continuous) there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in B(x_0,\delta)$ $$d(f(x),f(x_0)) \lt \varepsilon \lt 1.$$ But then by the discreteness of $Y$ it follows that $f(x) = f(x_0),$ for all $x \in B(x_0,\delta).$ So $f(x) \neq f(y),$ for all $x \in B(x_0,\delta).$ But this shows that $d(f(x),f(y)) = 1,$ for all $x \in B(x_0,\delta).$ Since $f$ is a contraction map it follows that for all $x \in B(x_0,\delta)$ $$1 = d(f(x),f(y)) \leq c\ d(x,y)$$ for some $0 \lt c \lt 1.$

Does it lead to any contradiction?

Comment: In your terminology, does a "discrete metric space" have a fixed metric, or is it a metric space with the discrete topology?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I think the discrete metric space has a fixed metric endowed with it called the discrete metric (which takes only two values $0$ and $1$) which I also call $d$ as in the metric in the domain space (by abuse of notation).

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. If $X=(0,1) \cup (4,5)$ with the usual metric and $Y=\{1,2\}$ with discrete metric then $f=1$ on $(0,1)$ and $2$ on $(4,5)$ defines  contraction (with $c=\frac 1 2 $) which is not  a constant. I think the only conclusion we can draw is that $f$ is a  constant in a neighborhood of each point.

Comment: You are right @Kavi Rama Murthy sir. It's an exercise of S. Kumaresan's **Topology of metric spaces.** Exercise 6.4.4. Page no. 152 (Second edition).